# Stack Exchange search does not use results per page (even on first navigation)

Tags: bug

When running a simple search, if you change the number of results per page, that choice is applied immediately for the current page, but is ignored on any subsequent navigation and must be changed on every page load.

Steps to reproduce:

- **Go to the main Stack Exchange search**

  - [Searching for "Danger! Will Robinson!"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=danger+will+robinson) will return ~200 results
  - Default set to "30 per page", with 7 pages of results
- **Switch to "50 per page"**

  - There are now 4 pages of results
- **Click "Next" or the little round page "2"**

  - Per page reverts to the default of 30, with 7 pages of results, once again

Also, clicking on the 15, 30, or 50 automatically takes you back to the first page of results.